# How use and operator in where clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

This code return 3 row, but must return 1 row. How can i use 'and' operator in where clause?

```
BEGIN
SELECT auth.username,users.id,users.id_registration_type,users.name, users.surname,
       users.corp_name,users.work_duration,users.photo,
       like_dislike.like_count,like_dislike.dislike_count
FROM   users
LEFT JOIN auth
      ON users.id=auth.id     
LEFT JOIN like_dislike
      ON users.id=like_dislike.id  
LEFT JOIN registration_type
      ON  registration_type.id_type = users.id_registration_type  
LEFT JOIN users_region
      ON users.id=users_region.id_users
LEFT JOIN users_work_area
      ON users.id=users_work_area.id_users
WHERE (users_region.id_region = region) 
      AND (users_work_area.id_area = area_type)
      AND (registration_type.id_type = reg_type)

LIMIT shows,limits;
END
```

it must return 1 row. [image]

Comment: you tagged as php with no code to support the question. If you're using some type of loop, show it. Otherwise, do a GROUP BY or DISTINCT in your query. We also don't know what your LIMIT is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, i'm delete php  tag. How can I use distinct? example please.

Comment: See the docs on both http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/distinct-optimization.html - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html and remove LIMIT. @FaridValiyev you don't really need it if you're going to use GROUP BY / DISTINCT.

Comment: Thanks for help everybody. Distinct solved my problem :)

Comment: @FaridValiyev You're welcome.

Comment: And change the last three outer joins to inner joins (which they actually are based on the WHERE-conditions)

Comment: @dnoeth You're welcome to edit the (community) wiki answer below if you wish. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting as a community wiki.**

Sidenote: Rep points do not count when posted as such, just so y'all know (*wink*).

You can use DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/distinct-optimization.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html